# How do I call a local method in my class by an intent in alarmManager?

Tags: android, methods, service, alarmmanager

For example:

Public class Calls extends Service {
    public void onCreate()
    {
      //call myMethod here by alarmManager
   }

myMethod()
   {

}
}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I missing something, but why you just do this?

```
public class Calls extends Service {
   public void onCreate() {
      myMethod();
   }

   myMethod() {

   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. But I need to call my method in schedule. So the only solution I could think of is to use the alarmManager. But instead of calling a class, I need to call a local method.